# Add new column to individual options?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, adminhtml, catalog, backend

I try to add radio buttons to all individual options (**Catalog -> Manage Articles -> Open a configurable article -> Individual Options**) so that the backend user can pick which one he likes to be selected by default.

Example:

[image: Radio Buttons]

Do I need to create an extension and add a new EAV attribute? How does it work?

I found out that I can add a new column if I edit the template file **app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\type\select.phtml**

But I also need the value to stay saved and need to know how I can access the new value.